# Зашифровать и расшифровать файл по ключу

Tags: python, шифрование, криптография

Как зашифровать файл по ключу для последующей расшифровки?

Как собственнно это происходит? Каков принцип? Я знаю, что любой файл - это набор байтов. При шифрование дополняются/заменяются эти байты? Или как?

Приведите, пожалуйста, пример шифровки/расшифровки файла по ключу

Comment: Начинай с изучения алгебры и теории чисел.

Comment: @typemoon: свои криптографические примитивы плодить -- это плохая идея. Нужно использовать готовые инструменты такие как `gpg`, [`cryptography`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cryptography)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы знакомы с волшебной функцией XOR ? Ключ - это тоже набор байтов, допустим пусть для простоты примера будет 1 байт. Теперь последовательно сложите этот байт ключа функцией XOR со всеми байтами файла. Вы получите изменившийся, зашифрованный файл. А теперь снова сложите изменившийся файл функцией XOR с байтом ключа. Вы получите исходный, расшифрованный файл. Это самый простой способ для примера.

Comment: То есть, для шифрования достаточно открыть исходный файл-получить содержимое-зашифровать содержимое-записать получившиеся данные ?

Comment: Да, и передать ключ тому для кого предназначен зашифрованный файл.